# CSS *:not(div p) does not select anything

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following a HTML code:

```
<div>
    <p> linux version</p>
    <h1> new tool </h1>
```

And some CSS for it that should select `<h1>` but does not select anything.

```css
*:not(div p) {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

The following does not work too:

```css
*:not(div>p) {}
```

I have so many such `<div>` `<p>` in the HTML whereas the following selects and apply the font:

```css
div p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Can you show some code?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation

Comment: If you're asking why it doesn't work, it is because the selector specification says that `:not()` only takes a simple selector (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn).

Comment: You can only use [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) with [`:not(…)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation).

Comment: then how can i select everything except div p elements

Comment: As others have stated, it isn't a part of the CSS specifation. While the specs never stopped browser vendors from adding unique advanced features, this one isn't implemented in any known browser. You'll have to resort to javascript, or server site generated class names.

Comment: If it helps, the jQuery `:not()` (and also `:has()`) take any selector..?

Comment: While the question before editing was confusing, and still isn't totally crisp and clear writing, it *is* obvious to CSS3 experts what the problem is.

Comment: @DarenW: As a CSS3 expert, I agree, hence my initial comment. We do, however, want to encourage asking comprehensible questions in the first place. That is why questions can be closed and later reopened by votes. On a side note, I like how all the downvotes on the original question have disappeared since the question was restored and reopened.

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated in the comments: the usage of the not selector is like this:

```
E:not(s) - an E element that does not match simple selector s
```

where

```
A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector, 
attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.
```

So if you want you code to work you'll have to add a class to the `<p>` elements which you don't want styled with that font-family.

```
*:not(.classname) {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

---

Alternatively: If you need to apply a font to all your elements - it is generally done by setting it in the body element, then the other elements in the document inherit that rule.

Then you can style your `<p>` elements within the div differently.

```
body
{
   font-family: sans-serif;
}

div p
{
  /* the special font-family that you need for paragraphs within a div */
}
```

Comment: Other elements inherit it. Cascading has a different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it won't be exactly the same thing, but in this case you can use

`div>*:not(p)`

instead of

`*:not(div>p)`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/zc3u8/)

Comment: That worked for me, while *:not(whatever) wasn’t working. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
    <p> linux version</p>
    <h1> new tool </h1>`
</div>
```

Now consider the following CSS code-

```
*:not(div p) {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

This code selects all elements except the `<p>` inside `<div>`. So a `<div>` is also selected by the selector `*:not(div p)` and hence all the contents of the `<div>` gets the style: `font-family: sans-serif`. So the text in the `<p>` element in the `<div>` also gets the style.

***N.B. You should keep track so that two CSS declaration don't contradict each other. Then if such contradiction arises the declaration that applies some style wins over the declaration that forbids that style to be applied on that element.***

Hence the following code will run fine

```
div>:not(p)
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

This selector will select the elements inside a `<div>` except `<p>`-elements. So you may use this instead.

Answer (score -1):

It seems in your question, that given the markup:

```
<div>
  <p>linux version</p>
  <h1> new tool </h1>
</div>
```

<h1> elements are the special ones. So be specific. Rather than define styles for "all-but-me" (as you do with "*:not(div p)" clause) set and standard for "all-of-them" and then you overwrite the one you consider special. Just like here:

```
div {
  font-family: serif;
}

div > h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly the same as the OP needs.