# :not all of child element use css?

Tags: html, css

I have some child element of selector and I want to set property for all elements except this selector. I use this code:

```css
*:not(#element):not(#element *) {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="element">
  <p>Something</p>
</div>
<p>font size is 14px</p>
```

But it doesn't work.

If I use `*:not(#element)` it works, but if I use `*:not(#element *)` it doesn't.

Comment: See this answer ► [CSS \*:not(div p) does not select anything](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20774599/448144) It explains that only simple selectors work when using `:not()` and how you can work around it.

Comment: And even if `:not(#element *)` would be valid, it would still 1) have been written as `*:not(#element), :not(#element *)` with a comma in between, and 2) it wouldn't have worked, since the parent of the div, let's say the body, will be given the font size, and font sizes inherit, so you would still get the same size rather than what it would have been in the absence of any CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply inverse your selector and specify that `#element` and `#element *` has some different font:

```css
* {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#element,
#element * {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="element">
  <p>Something</p>
</div>
<p>font size is 14px</p>
```